# Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, angular8, azure-ad-msal

I am using msal for angular 8 and .NET core 2.2 for webapi. I create token from my angular App and want to verify for webapi.
I have registered my both app (angular and localhost webapi) in Azure portal and exposed api also.
Below is my app.module.ts file content :

```
let msalConfig: MsalConfig;
export function initializeApp(appConfig: AppConfig) {
  const promise = appConfig.loadAppConfig().pipe(tap((settings: IAppConfig) => {

    const protectedResourceMap:[string, string[]][]=
    [ 
      ['http://localhost:7308/api/values',['api://{azure-web-api-app-clientID}/values']], 
    ];
    msalConfig = {
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{azure-tenantId}',
      clientID: 'azure-angular-api-app-clientID',
      protectedResourceMap: protectedResourceMap,
      validateAuthority: true,
      isAngular:true,
      piiLoggingEnabled:true,

      cacheLocation : "localStorage",
      redirectUri: "http://localhost:8081/",
      storeAuthStateInCookie: true
    };
  })).toPromise();
  return () => promise;
}

export function msalConfigFactory() {
  return msalConfig;
}
```

And below is providers in app.module.ts

```
providers: [ 
    ProductService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeApp,
      deps: [AppConfig],
      multi: true
    },
    MsalService,
    {
      provide: MSAL_CONFIG,
      useFactory: msalConfigFactory
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
]
```

And for Asp.net core 2.2 webapi startup.cs file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddCors(options =>
     {
            options.AddPolicy("EnableCors", builder =>
            {
                 builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8081").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
             });
      });
       services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
       {
             sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme;
       })
       .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureActiveDirectory", options));

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
         app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
         app.UseCors("EnableCors");
         app.UseAuthentication();
         app.UseStaticFiles();
         app.UseMvc();
 }
```

and in appsettings.json

```
"AzureActiveDirectory": {
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "Domain": "{my-domain}.onmicrosoft.com",
        "TenantId": "{azure-web-app-api-tenantid}",
        "ClientId": "azure-web-api-app-clientID"
    }
```

When I try to call this api,I'm getting 500 error. It's not even point to api (/api/values).

Exact error is,

**IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my-tennantId}/.well-known/openid-configuration'**

Comment: Sounds like something is blocking the request from your front-end to get the metadata document. Do you have a firewall in place that blocks it? Do you have an Internet connection? What happens if you enter that URL into the browser directly?

Comment: Any update for this issue?